# TreasuryDirect.gov not showing monthly interest gained on an I bond

Tags: united-states, bonds, interest, treasury

I bought an I bond on treasurydirect.gov and it was filled on 10/1/2022 (more than 1 month ago at the time of writing). My understanding is that I bonds accrue interest monthly but when I login now it still shows the original principal value. This is true not only at the aggregate screens but even when I drill all the way down the holding details of the bond

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They don't include the interest for the last 3 months until the holding period requirements are met. So you'll start seeing interest accruals in 3 months. After 5 years of holding they'll add the last 3 months interest as well.